# Density of eigenvalues of empirical covariance matrix of vectors uniform on the sphere

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, random-matrices

Is anyone able to point me to a reference for this?

Let the rows of $X \in \Re^{n\times d}$ be i.i.d. uniform on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{d}$ in $\Re^d$. What is the density of the eigenvalues of $X^\top X$?

Comment: are the rows independent? closed-form expressions for arbitrary $n,d$ are unlikely; are you interested in asymptotics for $n,d\gg 1$?

Comment: Yes, the rows are independent. I'm after the exact value for fixed $n$ and $d$. It is known when the rows are gaussian random vectors. E.g. Corollary 3.2.19 of Robb J Muirhead. Aspects of multivariate statistical theory. Vol. 197. John Wiley & Sons, 2009. 

I would expect it to be known in the uniform case too, right?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to get somewhere using theorem 1 of these notes

https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/386/ClassicalEnsembles.pdf

but in my case it seems diagonal entries don't have a density

Comment: in your case the martrix elements are correlated, since the squares must sum to $d$, that is an essential complication compared to the case of independent Gaussians; for $d\gg 1$ the correlations can be neglected, but not for small $d$.

Comment: Is an asymptotic result available for this setting, if an exact one is not?

Answer (score 1):

For $d\gg 1$ the elements of $X$ have independent normal distributions (mean zero, unit variance). If you also take the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$, at fixed ratio $n/d$, the eigenvalues of $X^\top X$ have the [Marchenko-Pastur density.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution)